# How "Data-container" directory mount to host directory to save persisted data

Tags: docker

I am trying to Dockerize my Rails application.

Currently I have two containers:

1. "Data-container". In this container is Rails application code and
   all necessary gems. "Data-container" is exposing volumes of Rails application root directory and gem directory
2. "Web sever container". In this container is running Nginx +
   Passenger. "Web sever container" is binded to "Data-container" volumes.

All works fine.

But I need that all logs and user uploaded images (stored under Rails application root directory "public/images") directory is backup on host directory.
I know that I can start new container which connects to "Data-container" and make some backup to host directory. But this approach is not really what I try to achieve. 
I want that all logs and images is immediate and all-time written on host directory.

I try to mount host directory to "Data-container" directory which data I wanted to be stored on host machine, but this approach is not working.

### Start and inspect "Data-container"

```
docker run --name application -v $HOME/cabin/data/log:/opt/application/log -v $HOME/cabin/data/images:/opt/application/public/images foo/application

docker inspect application

"Volumes": {
    "/opt/application": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/0c2a96af0e13d2b1c451610dc7bd561cffd246564e1966cb55628d329b4ee62b",
    "/opt/application/log": "/home/vagrant/cabin/data/log",
    "/opt/application/public/images": "/home/vagrant/cabin/data/images",
    "/webapp_gems": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/b2a08475272e1a04eae121094c0369a38c22dd92ca76fc2c2418eeabea31e266",
    "/webapp_lib64": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/44df839567e15c471e3ccd33a28778d7f67496c32f6110703d4d5e15677e00f6"
},
"VolumesRW": {
    "/opt/application": true,
    "/opt/application/log": true,
    "/opt/application/public/images": true,
    "/webapp_gems": true,
    "/webapp_lib64": true
}
```

### Start and inspect "Web sever container"

```
docker run -d -p 9101:9101 --name server -v $HOME/cabin/data/log:/var/log/nginx -v $HOME/cabin/data/run:/var/run/nginx -v $HOME/cabin/configuration/nginx:/etc/nginx --volumes-from application foo/server nginx -c /etc/nginx/demo.conf


docker inspect server

"Volumes": {
    "/etc/nginx": "/home/vagrant/cabin/configuration/nginx",
    "/opt/application": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/0c2a96af0e13d2b1c451610dc7bd561cffd246564e1966cb55628d329b4ee62b",
    "/opt/application/log": "/home/vagrant/cabin/data/log",
    "/opt/application/public/images": "/home/vagrant/cabin/data/images",
    "/var/log/nginx": "/home/vagrant/cabin/data/log",
    "/var/run/nginx": "/home/vagrant/cabin/data/run",
    "/webapp_gems": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/b2a08475272e1a04eae121094c0369a38c22dd92ca76fc2c2418eeabea31e266",
    "/webapp_lib64": "/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/44df839567e15c471e3ccd33a28778d7f67496c32f6110703d4d5e15677e00f6"
},
"VolumesRW": {
    "/etc/nginx": true,
    "/opt/application": true,
    "/opt/application/log": true,
    "/opt/application/public/images": true,
    "/var/log/nginx": true,
    "/var/run/nginx": true,
    "/webapp_gems": true,
    "/webapp_lib64": true
}
```

By running application in **/home/vagrant/cabin/data/log** and **/home/vagrant/cabin/data/images** is not written any data from application container

### My environment

```
docker info

Containers: 2
Images: 92
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-8:1-524459-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 64 Kb
 Data file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Data Space Used: 7605.2 Mb
 Data Space Total: 102400.0 Mb
 Metadata Space Used: 8.3 Mb
 Metadata Space Total: 2048.0 Mb
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Kernel Version: 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64
Operating System: <unknown>
```

.

```
docker version

Client version: 1.2.0
Client API version: 1.14
Go version (client): go1.3.1
Git commit (client): fa7b24f
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.2.0
Server API version: 1.14
Go version (server): go1.3.1
Git commit (server): fa7b24f
```

.

```
uname -a

Linux vagrant-centos65.vagrantup.com 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 3 21:39:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

.

```
cat /etc/redhat-release

CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You can run another container for test the volumen.
docker run -t -i --name application_test -v $HOME/cabin/data/log:/opt/application/log -v $HOME/cabin/data/images:/opt/application/public/images foo/application /bin/bash

You get a shell. Try to write some thing on /opt/application/public/images.

Then check your directory $HOME/cabin/data/images